# Does macOS come with (the ruby framework) rails?

Tags: macos, ruby

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474875/why-does-mac-os-x-come-with-ruby-rails) question seems to imply OS X/macOS comes with the ruby framework ***rails***. Is this correct? (I always thought OS X/macOS comes with ruby, but ***not*** rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, **macOS** does not come with `rails` preinstalled.

On a default clean install of **macOS Catalinia**, if you run the following *command* in **Terminal**, you'll see that `rails` is not installed by default.

```
% rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
%
```

I also tested this on some earlier versions of **macOS** and the result was the same.

If `rails -v` returns version info, then it's installed, but was done after **macOS** was originally installed.